# How does proxy server know which client is the recipient of a response?

Tags: proxy, port-forwarding, nat, reverse-proxy, load-balancer

In Network Address Translation, port number is used to determine which client is the recipient of a response from a server.

But how about in proxy? Let's say we have two clients, `clientA` and `clientB`, connected to a proxy server, and let's say they access `youtube.com` at the same time. Now when the proxy server receives the response from `youtube.com`, how does it know if that response if for `clientA` or for `clientB`? Is port number also used here in a way like in NAT?

Answer (score 2):

The requests come into the proxy as separate HTTPS requests over separate TCP connections, and the proxy makes separate HTTPS requests to the real server (YouTube in your example) over separate TCP connections. TCP connections are uniquely identified by the 4-tuple of (source IP, source port, dest IP, dest port). The proxy keeps track of which incoming request connection from a client relates to which outgoing request connection it makes.

Comment: ok, so there is a one-to-one mapping of client-to-proxy-tuple and proxy-to-server-tuple, right?

Comment: @Noob_Guy Yes, that's correct.

Comment: There's a separate TCP connection between each of the client to the proxy but I doubt if it's a separate TCP connection between the proxy and the backend server(considering all requests from the clients are hitting only 1 backend server). Am I right on this?

As per my understanding, packets moving from client to proxy would have destination address as that of the proxy(considering reverse proxy in this case) while the destination address for proxy to backend would be that of backend server. So, when the backend server returns back the response, it sets the destination address as proxy.

Comment: and when the proxy sends back the response, how does it know to which client it needs to forward the response based on the packets it received from the backend server? Bcz. the packet from backend server to the proxy contain the source:backend and destination:proxy without differentiating on which source client sent the request.

Comment: If a unique TCP connection is established b/w the proxy and backend(considering only 1 server for now) for every TCP connection b/w the client-proxy then it would limit the no. of tcp connection b/w the proxy and the backend to 64k.

Comment: @ajaysinghnegi If your sysadmins (site reliability engineers) see that you're approaching the 64Ki limit of simultaneous connections between the proxy and the backend, they could add more listening ports on the backend server. Also, I didn't get into this in my Answer, but if the requests to the backend need to be multiplexed over a single connection, it would have to use HTTP/2 or later, which have their own mechanisms for multiplexing multiple simultaneous requests over a single connection/flow.